# Trigger to check condition and update table at particular time interval, if condition holds in sql server wpf

Tags: sql, wpf, sql-server-2012

I am using WPF to create an app and I'm using SQL Server 2012 as the backend. I want to update a table based on the date condition like suppose if the date in the datatable is 09/02/2015 and today's system date is 09/02/2015, then all the records in the table having this date should be updated. Please anyone help me with this.

Comment: whats your findings ?

Comment: I am using WPF to create an app and I'm using SQL Server 2012 as the backend. I want to update a table based on the date condition like suppose if the date in the datatable is 09/02/2015 and today's system date is 09/02/2015, then all the records in the table having this date should be updated. Please anyone help me with this.

Comment: Please provide sample Input data and your expected Output

Comment: I want trigger that needs to be executed every 5 mins to check whether the date and time column in the tblSample table matches or exceeds the System Date And Time. If the condition holds true then I want the status column of TblSample table set to be false.